# Spring Connection Pooling

Tags: spring, connection-pooling

Can someone tell me or point me to a document/tutorial that explains how to use connection pooling in Spring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring doesn't support inbuilt pooling. You should use a third party pool as mentioned above. DBCP and [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) both work like a charm with spring. All you need to do is when defining a datasource in your context.xml, just use DBCP to define it.

Answer (score 9):

You might use a pooled datasource from the jdbc driver. E.g. in oracles library there is one:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@wherever:1234:whatever" />
    <property name="user" value="theuser" />
    <property name="password" value="thepassword" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Spring doesn't include a pooled DataSource... you can use Apache DBCP for that, if you need a connection pool in a J2SE application. For container-hosted apps, you should configure a DataSource in the container and use it from your app.

Comment: +1, experimented (with Apache DBCP) in a recent project.