# Spring JDBC connection pool best practices

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp

I have a basic Spring JDBC application with a pretty basic configuration:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:XXX"/>
   <property name="username" value="username"/>
   <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dbThing" class="com.DbThing">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I would like to introduce a connection pool, and after reading several threads on SO I am a bit confused about which pooling library to use.

The libraries that seem to have more credits on SO are [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html) and [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). Since I'm using Oracle, I could also use the [pooled data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777372/spring-connection-pooling/2041171#2041171) offered by the driver.

I understand that there are more libraries available - for instance the new Apache Tomcat 7 pooling libraries.

Is there any library that I should really avoid?

Is there any recommended configuration I should use with a given library?

Any "war story" you care to share?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C3PO and DBCP development have stalled mostly because they are mature. I have seen both of these drivers be able to support hundreds of transactions per second.

The Tomcat pool is a reworked & updated DBCP driver. MyBatis 3.0 also contains it's own pooling implementation which, based on code inspection, seems solid. Finally, there's [BoneCP](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp) which claims to have the best performance. I haven't used any of these on a project yet.

Probably the best advice is to pick any of them test it. Spring makes it easy to swap out later.

Comment: BoneCP is not active anymore.  You can also look at HikariCP which is a fixed connection pool and have a great performance benefits.  [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for their webpage.

Answer (score 17):

As an alternative to BoneCP, have you perhaps tried Oracle's own database connection pool?

I've had good experiences for the last couple of weeks, so it might be worth giving it a shot - also, I suppose Oracle would know a thing or two about making a connection pool especially when paired up with their own database.

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**: Also, if you're using (one of) the latest Oracle JDBC drivers (11.2.0.1+), you may want to try out the new Universal Connection Pool. The `OracleConnectionPoolDataSource` seems to be officially deprecated in favour of this pool. However, some users have reported errors using it, so it may be too early. I am in a position to use Oracle's latest JDBC drivers, so I will give it a try and update here as soon as have any info on this.

More info on this SO thread: [Oracle UCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427890/oracledatasource-vs-oracle-ucp-pooldatasource)

Answer (score 10):

`BoneCP` has been claiming but then a new tool is introduced named `HiKariCP` it has overcomed many drawbacks which were present in pass tools you can configure it by below change in `application-context.xml`

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
  <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="minimumPoolSize" value="2" />
  <property name="dataSourceClassName" 
            value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
  <property name="dataSourceProperties" ref="props" />
  <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
      <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:datasource.properties"/>
```

where in `database.properties` you should provide details of database like below

```
 url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:port:SID/Databasename
 user=usernmae
 password=password
```

For proper demo you can use [this link](http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.in/2013/12/spring-hikaricp-with-pivotal-gemfirexd.html)

Comment: thanks for answering this, it helps take the load off of us HikariCP developers.

Comment: your welcome @brettw if its help ful to you you can up vote it :)

Comment: Thanks for point out HiKaRi!.A small update of the hikariConfig. Don't know how to format a comment:
    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="50"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

Answer (score 6):

Definately you can use C3P0, this is developed for enterprise solution. To Check advantages you can [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837602/3073945).

**Here is the example code of integration:**

```
@Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

This Bean is for getting `JpaTransactionManager`.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("YOUR.DATABSE.ENTITY.PACKAGE");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

This Bean is for getting `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. It Takes `DataSource` ,`PersistenceProviderClass` , Entity Package Name `PackagesToScan` and JpaProperties from `hibProperties()`.

```
@Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }
```

Here, `env value are comming from application.properties`.

Check bellow properties:

```
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
hibernate.show_sql: false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
```

**The main part is DataSource Setup. That is given bellow**:

```
@Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource(){
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
            dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("minPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxIdleTime")));
            dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxStatements")));
            dataSource.setMaxStatementsPerConnection(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxStatementsPerConnection")));
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(10000);

        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
```

It is using `ComboPooledDataSource` that is taking many more important parameter's like maxPoolSize,MinPoolSize, MaxIdleSize etc.
**It's environment parameter are given bellow:**

```
db.driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver // for Oracle
db.username: YOUR_USER_NAME
db.password: YOUR_USER_PASSWORD
db.url: DATABASE_URL
minPoolSize:5 // number of minimum poolSize
maxPoolSize:100 // number of maximum poolSize
maxIdleTime:5 // In seconds. After that time it will realease the unused connection.
maxStatements:1000
maxStatementsPerConnection:100
maxIdleTimeExcessConnections:10000
```

**Here is the full working sample code:**

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Scope("singleton")
public class TestDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource(){
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
            dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("minPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxIdleTime")));
            dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxStatements")));
            dataSource.setMaxStatementsPerConnection(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxStatementsPerConnection")));
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(10000);

        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Another things. Here is the gradle link

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.2.10.Final'
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks :)