# Dbcp connection pooling create more conncetion as expected

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am new in `DBCP`.
   I am using `DBCP connection pool` with `Spring` and `hibernate` ,`Database` is `MYSQL`.
   I am unable to find how many `connections` are created in `connection pool`.
  Every time it's giving different processlist count.

I am using configuration is:

```
 <code>
 dbcp.maxActive =11
 dbcp.maxIdle =70
 dbcp.validationQuery=SELECT 1
 dbcp.minIdle =6
 dbcp.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=34000
 dbcp.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 55000
 dbcp.testOnBorrow =true
</code>
```

Please help me out if any one having idea.
   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `dbcp connection` pool is 8 `connections`, so if you want to run 9 simultaneous queries one of them will be blocked.
From the javadocs, you should be able to read this from the [getNumIdle()](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#getNumIdle%28%29) and [getNumActive()](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#getNumActive%28%29) methods, if you can get an instance of the BasicDataSource 
or connect to the database and 
run `exec sp_who2` which will show you what is connected, and active, and whether any queries are being blocked.
One suggestion is their if you are aware about it `DBCP`,it has more issues and I would suggest you to use `HikariCP`, it has got the most of it (ideal for performance related tasks) here the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442672/2749470) which will give you a useful for demo and lastly use `Spring's SimpleJdbcTemplate` which are more involved in simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am a HikariCP developer.  I would also of course recommend [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), but basically DBCP is one of the poorest pools out there.  If not HikariCP, try Tomcat DBCP or Vibur.  If you enable DEBUG logging for HikariCP, it is not "noisy" at all, and you will get pool statistics logged every 30 seconds.

Comment: thanks for the info @brettw I didn't know about `DEBUG` :) THANKS AGAIN