# Get JDBC connection from EntityManager

Tags: jpa, connection, eclipselink

I've a web application that uses EJB 3. Persistence is managed by container so the entity manager is injected.

```
@PersistenceContext(name="Ejbs", type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager em;
```

I need in one of my EJB methods to get the jdbc connection. I've read that it is possible with the next code:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

But I'm always getting null.

Why? How could I obtain the underlying connection?

UPDATE:

After changing the datasource definition it started to work. I remove a line of my datasource definition and it started to work. The line I've removed was

```
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
```

My datasource definion is:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/Unificado" pool-name="Unificado" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.12.54.186:1522:prd</connection-url>                    
      <driver>ojdbc6</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>unificado</user-name>
         <password>*******</password>
      </security>
      <validation>                        
         <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
         <background-validation>false</background-validation>
      </validation>
      <statement>
         <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
      </statement>
</datasource>
```

Comment: Why don't you just inject the DataSource that the EntityManager is getting its connection from? Or executing native queries with the EntityManager?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't execute native queries because i want to execute a stored procedure with blob parameters.

Comment: Perhaps the docs for your JPA implementation have some note for that. The one I use (DataNucleus JPA) provides me access to their internal wrapper for the underlying connection.

Comment: I don't think it is a matter of the JPA implementation. I've deployed the application on a JBoss 7.1. When I test the application in a jboss installed on Windows it works properly, but when I test the application in a a jboss installed on Linux, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using hibernate for your implementation?

Comment: No, I'm using EclipseLink

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done but it works now. I've just changed how the datasource was defined in standalone.xml. I'm going to update my question with the datasource definition.

Answer (score 4):

valid only for Spring framework

inject:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and get connection using:

```
    EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
    Connection connection = info.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Comment: Where to import EntityManagerFactoryInfo from?

Comment: Spring framework related Only , please add this info to your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get connection using bellow way:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(connection -> doSomeStuffWith(connection));
```

How you get EntityManager?

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Here is the imports:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.hibernate.Session;
```

Now, if you have problem on connection pooling then check [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838455/3073945)

Hope this will help you.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used

```
    //... some insert and update on EntityManager
    SessionImplementor sessionImp = (SessionImplementor) em.getDelegate();
    Connection con = sessionImp.connection();
```

to get JDBC connection as suggested in other answers but in my case I had also to flush the entity manager

```
    em.flush();
```

in order to "see" in my selects all the entities previously persisted both using em and repositories.

Comment: Where does SessionImplementor come from ?